# Pass non-library Java class type into JSP tagfile as attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am trying to write a JSP 2.0 tagfile which will accept an object of a non-library Java type as an attribute.

For example:

package org.myapp.model: Question.java

```
public Class Question {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    public getName() { return name; }
    public getType() { return type; }
    ...
}
```

displayQuestion.tag

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="question" required="true" type="org.myapp.model.Question"%>
<h2>
    <div>Question ${question.name} is of type ${question.type}</div>
</h2>
```

When I deploy my webapp I get an error: 'Unknown attribute type (org.myapp.model.Question) for attribute question.' If I leave off the type it defaults to String, and of course question.name and question.type fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the class present in the webapp's classpath (i.e. in WEB-INF/classes or in a jar of WEB-INF/lib)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding import to the tag?

```
 <%@ tag body-content="empty" import="org.myapp.model.Question" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. All the import statement documentation I found was for using imports in <%@ page %> directives, which can't be used within a tag file.